# replace bindwithevent function in mootools 1.3 (upgrade from 1.2)

Tags: javascript, mootools, upgrade

Dear all,
as MooTools 1.3 is out now, i´m going to update some scripts. BindWithEvent is now deprecated and has to be replaced, but how?

See this:

```
new Element('div', [.....]).addEvent('click',this.close.bindWithEvent(this,true));
```

I´m quite sure it has to be some sort of a function

```
new Element('div', [.....]).addEvent('click',function (event) { ????? } );
```

But how to bind with the upper close event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Deprecated-Functions%3abindWithEvent),

#### Function method: `bindWithEvent`

This function has been deprecated.

#### Example how you could replace this method:

```
myElement.addEvent('click', function(e){
    myFunction.bind(bind, [e]);
});
```

Comment: fine, but:
in my example this would result to:
new Element().addEvent('click', function(e) { this.close.bind(bind,e);})

and therefore, this.close would get a different meaning inside the new function than before.

Comment: tbh, from what I gather, `bindWithEvent` was an considered an edgecase. i don't see why you can't just replicate the code it used to use - i know several people that did. **in any case**, you can `bind` the anon function to the class instance and then pass the event object as suggested above to the method: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ExS4f/